# Mustache.js - display key instead of value

Tags: jquery, mustache, handlebars.js

I am using this data here: http://pastie.org/3231052 - How can I display the key instead of the value using Mustache or Handlebars?

```
[{"interval":"2012-01-21",
  "advertiser":"Advertisers 1",
  "offer":"Life Insurance",
  "cost_type":"CPA",
  "revenue_type":"CPA",
  ... etc ...
}]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop over each item and display key-value pairs?

Comment: Yeah, so the key will be in <th> for X amount of them. Then the value in the <td> regardless of how many rows there are. Been struggling. Using jQuery throughout

Comment: In newer versions of Handlebars this is handled by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display key-value pairs, you can write a helper in Handlebars.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachkeys', function(context, options) {
  var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
  var ret = "";

  var empty = true;
  for (key in context) { empty = false; break; }

  if (!empty) {
    for (key in context) {
        ret = ret + fn({ 'key': key, 'value': context[key]});
    }
  } else {
    ret = inverse(this);
  }
  return ret;
});

$(function() {
    var data = {"interval":"2012-01-21",
      "advertiser":"Advertisers 1",
      "offer":"Life Insurance",
      "cost_type":"CPA",
      "revenue_type":"CPA"};
                
    var source   = $("#template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $('#content').html(template({'data': data}));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0.beta2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#eachkeys data}}
    <li>{{this.key}} - {{this.value}}</li>
    {{/eachkeys}}
</script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Seems like this isn't quite what you want, but it's possible to come up with a helper that will do the trick.

Comment: I think very similar to that where they key is in the <th>key here</th> for x amount of them returned in the string? Does that work?

Comment: Then the value in the <td> in the appropriate column based on the key

Comment: It would help to see an example of the HTML to you want to produce from the data. Is the data an array of objects? (It's unclear, since there's only one array element given.) If that's the case, you can simply loop over the array keys in the first element to produce the headers and then (assuming the columns are uniform throughout the data), populate the rows for each item.

Comment: I think I was able to get it. But what you wrote was the base idea. The back end dev was able to tweak the output of the data.

Answer (score -1):

I modified the previous response using Handlebars to handle objects key value pair. It is as simple as just doing the following:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{@entries}}
    <li>{{KEY}} - {{VALUE}}</li>
    {{/entries}}
</script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I put an example on Fiddle, hope it helps someone out there. Please note this implementation depends on Handlebars

[Mustache Attribute addition.](http://jsfiddle.net/CPrkV/32/)

Comment: this is not mustache

Comment: Can you be more specific, I guess you didn't see the link to fiddle

Comment: I  had a quick look, you call it as Handlebars , not as Mustache. Must be a different library, or?

Comment: Did you notice that the previous answer was based on using Handlebars?

Comment: The comments and answers are based around using handlebars. I'll update the answer, but make sure you also make the same comment about the other answer as well as the comments below the question.