# Showing fieldnames of mustache array

Tags: javascript, mustache

In the example below:

```
{{#content}}
        <tr>
        {{#show}}
        <td>{{ID}}</td><td>{{fieldname1}}</td><td>{{fieldname2}}</td>
        {{/show}}
        </tr>
{{/content}}
```

is it also possible to show the field/keynames themselves of the content array? Thus showing "fieldname1" and "fieldname2" instead of the values in these fields/keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Mustache.js cannot do this. You'll need to write a helper using something like Handlebars as outlined in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961939/mustache-js-display-key-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 0):

use : {{#each topLevelObject}}{{.}}{{/each}}