# How to get index in Handlebars each helper?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars for templating in my project. Is there a way to get the index of the current iteration of an "each" helper in Handlebars?

```
<tbody>
     {{#each item}}
         <tr>
            <td><!--HOW TO GET ARRAY INDEX HERE?--></td>
            <td>{{this.key}}</td>
            <td>{{this.value}}</td>
         </tr>
     {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can register your own helper to do this, for example: https://gist.github.com/1048968 or: http://pastebin.com/ksGrVYkz

Comment: I added another solution to the Gist example that works with handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js. https://gist.github.com/1048968#gistcomment-617934

Answer (score 566, accepted):

In the newer versions of Handlebars index (or key in the case of object iteration) is provided by default with the standard each helper.

---

snippet from : https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/250#issuecomment-9514811

The index of the current array item has been available for some time now via @index:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

For object iteration, use @key instead:

```
{{#each object}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this in various situations, every single time I get a error on the console.
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Comment: This works fine but make sure the '@' character is escaped if you use a web framework where @ has a special meaning :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue in rails with .hbs files. Not aware of how to escape the @ char is this environment?

Comment: It's worth noting that as of [v1.2.0](http://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md#v120---december-23rd-2013), `@index` and `@first` are now supported for each iteration on objects too.

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net MVC Razor you escape with @@, i.e. `{{@@index}}`

Comment: [Solve `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841340/what-is-the-correct-way-of-getting-the-index-of-an-array-when-iterating-over-it)

Comment: You can mix this with the `if` or `unless` helpers to do things like add a separator after the first item, e.g. `{{#if @@index}} <hr/> {{/if}}`

Comment: Any idea how I would get the index or key in Framework7 virtualList itemTemplate looper? I know it iterates an items object and uses handlebars. Can't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: how would you get a value from a previous item in the each helper? ie array(@index-1).date. Trying to check current date versus previous items.

Answer (score 20):

In handlebar version 3.0 onwards,

```
{{#each users as |user userId|}}
  Id: {{userId}} Name: {{user.name}}
{{/each}}
```

In this particular example, user will have the same value as the current context and userId will have the index value for the iteration.
Refer - http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html in block helpers section

Answer (score 19):

This has changed in the newer versions of Ember.

For arrays:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{_view.contentIndex}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

It looks like the #each block no longer works on objects. My suggestion is to roll your own helper function for it.

Thanks for this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841340/what-is-the-correct-way-of-getting-the-index-of-an-array-when-iterating-over-it).

Answer (score 14):

I know this is too late. But i solved this issue with following Code:

Java Script:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachData', function(context, options) {
      var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse, ctx;
      var ret = "";

      if(context && context.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
          ctx = Object.create(context[i]);
          ctx.index = i;
          ret = ret + fn(ctx);
        }
      } else {
        ret = inverse(this);
      }
      return ret;
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#eachData items}}
 {{index}} // You got here start with 0 index
{{/eachData}}
```

if you want start your index with 1 you should do following code:

Javascript:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachData', function(context, options) {
      var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse, ctx;
      var ret = "";

      if(context && context.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
          ctx = Object.create(context[i]);
          ctx.index = i;
          ret = ret + fn(ctx);
        }
      } else {
        ret = inverse(this);
      }
      return ret;
    }); 

Handlebars.registerHelper("math", function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue);
    rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue);

    return {
        "+": lvalue + rvalue
    }[operator];
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#eachData items}}
     {{math index "+" 1}} // You got here start with 1 index
 {{/eachData}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, you clarified that @index starts at 0, and provided a method to change it to 1 based index. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

Arrays:

```
{{#each array}}
    {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

If you have arrays of objects... you can iterate through the children:

```
{{#each array}}
    //each this = { key: value, key: value, ...}
    {{#each this}}
        //each key=@key and value=this of child object 
        {{@key}}: {{this}}
        //Or get index number of parent array looping
        {{@../index}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Objects:

```
{{#each object}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

If you have nested objects you can access the `key` of parent object with 
`{{@../key}}`

Answer (score 4):

Using loop in hbs little bit complex

```
<tbody>
     {{#each item}}
         <tr>
            <td><!--HOW TO GET ARRAY INDEX HERE?--></td>
            <td>{{@index}}</td>
            <td>{{this}}</td>
         </tr>
     {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

[Learn more](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each)

Answer (score 0):

In handlebar version 4.0 onwards,

```
{{#list array}}
  {{@index}} 
{{/list}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     <tbody>
>         {{#each courses}}
>         <tr>
>             <th scope="row">{{@index}}</th>
>             <td>{{this.name}}</td>
>             <td>{{this.description}}</td>
>             <td>{{this.createdAt}}</td>
>         </tr>
>         {{/each}}
>     </tbody>
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your index with 0

```
<tbody>
 {{#each item}}
     <tr>
        <td>{{@index}}</td>
        <td>{{this.key}}</td>
        <td>{{this.value}}</td>
     </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

If you want to start your index with 1.

In JavaScript

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('print', function(value) {
    return ++value
});
```

In HTML file

```
<tbody>
 {{#each item}}
     <tr>
        <td>{{print @index}}</td>
        <td>{{this.key}}</td>
        <td>{{this.value}}</td>
     </tr>
 {{/each}}
```