# Iterate over a json object array in blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor, and am struggling with using `#each` in blaze.
I tried following [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035363/meteor-and-handlebars-each-to-iterate-over-object), but my requirement is slightly different.

I have a json object array:

```
{
    "accounting": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "age": 23
        },

        {
            "firstName": "Mary",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "age": 32
        },

        {
            "firstName": "Mike",
            "lastName": "Nolan",
            "age": 21
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I display firstName from each object, using blaze (specifically using #each to iterate the array) in a meteor project.

I tried a lot of different ways, using multiple helper methods, but am not able to make it happen. If someone can please help.

Also, if it is not possible, please tell alternatives to achieve the same.

The data is coming from an API call, and the format of data is a json object, but is stored as a Session variable (so that's where I will be getting it from in the helper method, using `Session.get()`).

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, will do that.I do not understand why the down vote? I have tried to simplify my problem, to understand the concept, which I can then improvise and use in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to depend on where your data is coming from.  In my example you can replace my hard-coded variable with the source of your object.  If you add where it is coming from I can modify my solution.

Basically, you just return the array of objects inside of the JSON object with a helper function.  From there you can call the helper in an `#each` block, and reference `firstName` directly with `{{firstName}}`

**Template**

```
<template name="yourTemplateName">
    {{#each accounting}}
        {{firstName}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Helper**

```
Template.yourTemplateName.helpers({
    accounting: function () {
        var data = Session.get('apiResponse');
         //You return the array of objects, which can then be iterated with each
        if (!_.isEmpty(data)){
            return data.accounting;
        } else {
            return []
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Edited the question to include the source.

Comment: If you can get the object result of your API call into my solution it will work.  Just return the `accounting` array as I did.  EDIT: I see you're using session, updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the API response is in a session variable called apiResponse.

Define a helper as follows:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  response: function () { 
    return Session.get('apiResponse');
  }
});
```

In your template, call the response helper with a `#with` template tag to set a data context and inside this tag iterate over the accounting array using a `#each` template tag.

```
<body>
  {{#with response}}
    {{#each accounting}}
      <p>{{firstName}} {{lastName}} is {{age}} years old.</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
</body>
```

You will see this in your browser window -

```
John Doe is 23 years old.

Mary Smith is 32 years old.

Mike Nolan is 21 years old.
```