# Isolating template regions in meteor for easier DOM navigation

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

It is very useful to use `template.find` to locate DOM elements inside a specific template instance. But what happens when the template iterates `{{#each}}` over some tags without using a sub-template?

```
<template name="top">
  {{#each items}}
    <img src="{{src}}">
    <a href="{{url}}">Click me</a>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Tempalte.events(
  'click a': (event, template) ->
    template.find('img')           # This doesn't do the trick
                                   # Is there a better way?
)
```

**Is there a way to easily access the `img` element associated with the click event?**

I know I can use `event.target` or create another template an use it inside the `{{#each}}` block. I wonder if there is a better/shorter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an @index to the img to make it possible to select it (using js or CSS). [How to get index in Handlebars each helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper)

Comment: It seems `@index` is not yet implemented in Meteor's Handlebars implementation: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/489#issuecomment-11270564