# In meteor is there a way to access array index in spacebars

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using meteor Shark branch.

Is there a way to access array index inside each block helper in spacebars?

I am looking for something like this.

```
{{#each humans}}
  {{this.arrayIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper suggests that stock handlebars has `{{@index}}` for arrays and `{{@key}}` for objects. On the other hand, I think a custom template helper or a global handlebars helper would be more extensible.

Comment: @HubertOG Meteor in the shark branch its spacebars. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### meteor >= 1.2

Spacebars gained a lot of functionality in 1.2, including a native `@index`. Helpers are no longer needed to solve this problem - you can simply do this:

```html
<template name="showHumans">
  <ul>
    {{#each humans}}
      <li>{{@index}}: {{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

### meteor < 1.2

I saw a similar example using template helpers in the [meteor book](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) in the "animations" chapter. You can apply a `map` to the humans cursor in order to add an index like so:

```
Template.showHumans.helpers({
  humans: function() {
    return Humans.find({}, {sort: {hotness: -1}}).map(function(human, index) {
      human.rank = index;
      return human;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="showHumans">
  <ul>
    {{#each humans}}
      <li>{{rank}}: {{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: love the sort hotness -1. This works but there is some nested array inside the object that returns. That's why I am looking to access the index from the template.

Comment: Haha - glad you liked that. Did you try just doing a `fetch()` on the cursor, manipulating the sub-arrays, and then returning the whole array to the template? I don't know how else to do it since spacebars doesn't seem to support `@index`.

Comment: That's sad. I don't like this solution but had a haunch that it is the only way to go. In the Template Engine preview page on github it says it will support index with each helper but I guess I have to wait still. Thanks a lot.

Comment: rank works, name doesn't. any tips?

Comment: If you need a 1-based index, create a Template helper
`Template.registerHelper('count1', function(count) { return count + 1; });` and then use it like so... `{{count1 @index}}` ...in your spacebars template.

Answer (score 3):

As taken from the [spacebars documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Each):

> You can use a special variable @index in the body of #each to get the
>   0-based index of the currently rendered value in the sequence.

Answer (score -10):

In Meteor 1.0.2.1, you can do the following:

```
{{#each humans}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

This is because #each iterates through the array, making the this in each loop simply equal to the current value.

Comment: And how do you access the index inside the `#each` block?

Comment: "this" does not answer the original question.

Comment: This answer is severely out of date...and it missed the point of the OP's question.