# How can I get the index of an array in a Meteor template each loop?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Say I have an object, someObject:

```
{
  foo: "apple",
  myArray: ["abc", "def"]
}
```

And a template helper that looks like this (and works fine):

```
getArray: function(){
  var self = this;
  self.myArray = self.myArray || [];    
  return self.myArray;
}
```

How should I construct the html to get the array index?

I've tried:

```
<template name="someObject"> // takes someObject as data
  {{#each getArray}}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{WHAT GOES HERE?}}">{{this}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

In which case `this` successfully returns `"abc"` and `"def"`. Which is good. But how can I get the index of the array to put into the attribute `data-value`?

I've tried `this.index` directly but it's undefined. I also tried using a helper:

```
<template name="someObject"> // takes someObject as data
  {{#each getArray}}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{getindex}}">{{this}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

but in this helper `getIndex` when I console.log out `this` I see:

```
String {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", length: 3}
String {0: "d", 1: "e", 2: "f", length: 3}
```

Is it possible to get the index?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### meteor >= 1.2

Spacebars gained a lot of functionality in 1.2, including a native `@index`. Helpers are no longer needed to solve this problem - you can simply do this:

```
{{#each getArray}}
  <div class="item" data-value="{{@index}}">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

or, if you want to use the index inside a helper:

```
{{#each getArray}}
  <div class="item" data-value="{{someHelper @index}}">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

### meteor < 1.2

Sometime in the future, spacebars may offer the ability to determine the index directly in the template. However, as of this writing, the only way to get the index is to modify the result returned by the helper. For example you could have `getArray` return an array of objects which contain a `value` and an `index`, like this:

```
getArray: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.myArray = self.myArray || [];
  return _.map(self.myArray, function(value, index){
    return {value: value, index: index};
  });
}
```

And the template could use the index like this:

```
<template name="someObject">
  {{#each getArray}}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{index}}">{{value}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815713/in-meteor-is-there-a-way-to-access-array-index-in-spacebars) for a similar example with cursors.

It's worth mentioning that you probably don't need to store the index in the DOM itself via `data-value`, unless it's needed by an external plugin. As you can see in the example below, each `item` has a context with an index value. For more information, see [this blog post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/).

```
Template.someObject.events({
  'click .item': function() {
    console.log(this.index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Note. the data attribute is required for something out of my ability (or desire) to edit so I have no choice.

Comment: Tried this on Meteor 1.2.0.2 and @index still returns undefined.

Comment: How would you display @index + 1?  Eg. start from 1 rather than zero?

Comment: You'll need to use a helper. In the example above, `someHelper` could be implemented to return the value of its argument + 1.

Answer (score 20):

You can make this a reusable helper, too. It's handy to have:

JS:

```js
UI.registerHelper('addIndex', function (all) {
    return _.map(all, function(val, index) {
        return {index: index, value: val};
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
{{#each addIndex somearray}}
<div>
   {{index}}: {{value}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 9):

This change is  [coming](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560)
and you will be able to do `{{@index}}`. When meteor supports the most recent version of handlebars.

Comment: At the time I wrote this it was not released yet. Probably that is still the case :/

Comment: This was release as part of Meteor 1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can change getArray to return an array of tupples and store the index there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can just add index to the object and as long as you didnt have a key named index before it shouldnt obstruct anything this way works only with arrays of objects. Now if you have a array of values you should use Christan Fritz answer

```
UI.registerHelper("withIndex", function(obj) {
  obj = obj || [];
  _.each(obj, function (object, index) {
    obj[index].index = index;
  });
  return obj;
});

{#each withIndex fields}}
   <div class="form-group field" data-index="{{index}}">
      <label for="{{name}}">{{title}}</label> 
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with underscore too, assuming that you have subscribed your template to array of objects

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  objectsWithIndex: function() {
    _.map(this.objects, function(value, key) {
      return _.extend(value, {
        index: key
      });
    });
    return this.objects;
  }
});
```

and in your html...

```
<template name="someObject">
  {{#each objectsWithIndex}}
    <div class="item" data-value="{{index}}">{{value}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```