# Creating a numbered list for Meteor data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there a way to get "the number" for a numbered list of the items I have in a Meteor collection. I know I can do it in html, but I feel like it would be much easier to style if I could just drop something in the {{spacebars}}. If there's better terminology I could be using, please let me know. Something like this.

List of top 20 movies:

```
    {{#each movie}}
         Movie #{{number}} {{movie_name}} {{review_score}}
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: It would help if you post a snippet of code that you've tried, or something we can work with.

Comment: Ok, I added a little something. Where I have the word "number," is there a way to get the list number there?

Answer (score 1):

I do not properly understand your question, neither do I know much about *Meteor-Collections*, but in general, if you iterate over an Array and want to get the index of each element, you could do it easily with:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(e,i){ console.log(i+":"+e); })

 0:1
 1:2
 2:3
```

See MDN for [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I didn't even know I was looking for the word "index." Apparently, some versions of handlebars let you simply use {{@index}}, but not Meteor's version. I'll try to work with what you provided here and other solutions on Stack and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

There is **[pull request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560)** which does exactly what you want:

```
{{#each movie}}
   {{@index}}{{movie}}
{{/each}}
```

Until they merge it you can use other approach:

[How can I get the index of an array in a Meteor template each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225071/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-array-in-a-meteor-template-each-loop)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking to discover. That and the proper way to articulate the issue, which Thomas Junk clued me in on (I'll probably just wait for this to get implemented).

Answer (score 1):

Try it with using "map" from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#map).

I'm expecting you have movies in your "Movie" collection and they look something like this:

```
{
    title: "Shawshank Redemption",
    score: 92
},
{
    title: "Forrest Gump",
    score: 96
},
{
    title: "Green Mile",
    score: 91
},
{
    title: "The Godfather",
    score: 95
}
```

... and so on ...

And here is "yourTemplate" helper function:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    movie: function () {
        var loadMovies = Movie.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}, limit: 20}).fetch(); // added descending sorting by review score
        var array = _.map(loadMovies, function(movie, index) {
            return {
                    number: index+1, // incrementing by 1 so you won't get 0 at the start of the list
                    movie_name: movie.title,
                    review_score: movie.score
                   };
        });
        return array;
    }
});
```

So now you can use it in your template like this:

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    {{#each movie}}
         Movie #{{number}} {{movie_name}} {{review_score}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```