# In Spacebars, how to enter data between iterations {{# each}}?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm using [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) and [Meteor 1.2](http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.2). In `{{#each post}}`, how to enter data after a specific iteration. For example after the second iteration.

Example:
1º iteration |
2º iteration |
**data** |
3º iteration |
4º iteration ...

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626410/creating-a-numbered-list-for-meteor-data) with the added twist of wanting to do something extra on a specific iteration. You can have a template helper that compares the iteration number to your target and that way your template can add some extra content at specific iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, convert your cursor to an array and add an index attribute. You're also going to need a helper to check equality (or to tell you when the conditions are right to display something different):

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  post: function(){
    var cursor = Posts.find({}); // whatever your query is   
    var array = _.map(cursor, function(doc, index) {
      doc.iteration = index + 1; // add an 'iteration' key starting at 1 instead of 0
      return doc;
    });
    return array;
  },
  equals: function(a,b){ // determine equality of a and b for use in spacebars
    return a==b;
  }
});
```

Then in your html template:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each post}}
    Title: {{title}}
    {{#if equals iteration 2}} Second iteration {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```