# Cannot set property in meteor template helper

Tags: meteor, indexing, iteration, underscore.js

I am trying to get index of an array in a Meteor template each loop. 
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626410/creating-a-numbered-list-for-meteor-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800524/in-spacebars-how-to-enter-data-between-iterations-each?lq=1).

This is what I done:

```
Template.SpaceList.helpers({
    Spaces: function() {
        var cursor =  Spaces.find();   
        var array = _.map(cursor, function(doc, index) {
          doc.number = index + 1; 
          return doc;
        });
        return array;

    }
```

And this is the template:

```
<template name="SpaceList">
  <table >
   <tbody>

        {{#each Spaces}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{number}} <a href="{{pathFor 'SpaceDetails'}}" >{{title}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{pathFor 'EditSpace'}}" > Edit</a></td>       
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
 </table>

</template>
```

But I getting this error:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot set property 'number'
>   of null

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` does not return an array, but a cursor. You need to first use `fetch` before `_.map` knows how to handle this:

```
    var cursor =  Spaces.find().fetch();
```