# Meteor Spacebar

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, spacebars

I'm having problem accessing the index returned by Collection.find(). In HTML, I'm creating a carousel and I want to make the images dynamic. Before making it dynamic, here's what it looks like:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="img/homepage/sliders/1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/homepage/sliders/2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

After implementation, here's the new code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  {{#each sliders}}              
     <div class="item active">
       <img src="{{this.url}}">
     </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here's what my JS looks like:

```
Template.homepageSlider.helpers({
    sliders: function() {
        return HomepageSliders.find({}, {fields: {url:1}}).fetch();
    }
});
```

This sort of works fine, but I wanted to add the class 'active' only on first index. How should I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225071/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-array-in-a-meteor-template-each-loop

Comment: no, that's not a duplicate. The other question wanted to retrieve the index itself. Here the question is about html attributes that depend on the index, so the solution to the other question only gets you so far.

Comment: Could you please make a better title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

JS:

```
Template.homepageSlider.helpers({
    sliders: function() {
        return _.map(HomepageSliders.find({}, {fields: {url:1}}).fetch(),
                     function(val, index) { 
                          return {value: val, 
                                  class: (index == 0 ? "item active" : "item")} 
                     });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  {{#each sliders}}              
     <div class="{{this.class}}">
       <img src="{{this.value.url}}">
     </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian! But the solution does not work. Images were stacked up. I've checked the inspect element and looks like the class didn't append on the div.

Comment: that's probably because he called the attribute "active" in one function and then accessed it as "class" in the helper.

Comment: It now works! Just change the '{{this.class}}' to '{{this.active}}'. Thanks again! :)