# Multiple each index on Meteor Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, each, meteor-blaze

I'm using Blaze from Meteor for html template, and I have multiple loop like :

```
let objects = [{name: 'John', age: 18}, {name: 'Foo', age: 25}, {name: 'Bar', age: 35}]
let attrs = ['name', 'age']


{{#each objects}}
  <h3>Object {{@index}}</h3>
  {{#each attrs}}
    [...] // code here
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I know :

- `{{@index}}` is used to know the current loop index (so on `[..]` `{{@index}}` is a ref to index on attrs array
- `{{this}}` is used to know the current loop value (so on `[...]` `{{value}}` is `name` or `age`)
- `{{..}}` is a ref to the parent loop value (so on `[...]` `{{..}}` is the current object, on first loop)

Now, I want on `[...]` the current **index** for the `objects` loop. I search a lots on Google and Stackoverflow but didn't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huumm, News about Blaze allow new to create variable (with #let). An easy solution is:

```
let objects = [{name: 'John', age: 18}, {name: 'Foo', age: 25}, {name: 'Bar', age: 35}]
let attrs = ['name', 'age']


{{#each objects}}
  {{#let object=this object_idx=@index}}
    <h3>Object {{object_idx}}</h3>

    {{#each attrs}}
      Object idx {{object_idx}} | Object {{object}}
      Attr idx {{@index}} | Attr {{this}}
    {{/each}}

  {{/let}}
{{/each}}
```

**Updated:** You can even do `{{#each object in objects}}` since a while, avoid you to do `{{#let object=this}}`

```
{{#each object in objects}}
  {{#let object_idx=@index}}
    <h3>Object {{object_idx}}</h3>

    {{#each attr in attrs}}
      Object idx {{object_idx}} | Object {{object}}
      Attr idx {{@index}} | Attr {{attr}}
    {{/each}}

  {{/let}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: #let keyword makes hugs availability.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a helper for the inner loop as follows:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  value: function(){
    return Template.parentData(1)[this];
  }
});
```

`Template.parentData(1)` returns the data context one (1) level up from the current level. `[this]` references the key of that object given by the current data.

Comment: I want the index ! not the value

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't know that getting the index of the parent context is possible. I'd recommend that you *map* an index variable into your outer object array using @David Weldon's pattern from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24226769/2805154)