# Meteor template each loop, provide other template each X results

Tags: templates, if-statement, meteor, collections, each

Is it possible to insert specific data when meteor parse a collection with {{#each}} template logic only each X collection entry?

Exemple:

```
HTML
    {{#each collection}}
                 <div>
                    <p>{{collectionparam1}} - {{collectionparam2}}</p>
                    {{#if **collection[only multiple of 2]**}}
                       <p>I show this {{collectionparam3}} only each 2 entries</p>
                    {{/if}}
                 </div>      
    {{/each}}
```

Results:

```
Billy - 24
Joe - 12
I show this banana only each 2 entries
Bob - 88
Maria - 5
I show this cherry only each 2 entries
Samantha - 102
Henry - 43
I show this apple only each 2 entries
```

If possible, what do I have to put on {{#if}} logic?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225071/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-array-in-a-meteor-template-each-loop). Give this a try:

**html**

```html
{{#each collection}}
  <div>
    <p>{{collectionparam1}} - {{collectionparam2}}</p>
      {{#if shouldShow @index}}
        <p>I show this {{collectionparam3}} only each 2 entries</p>
      {{/if}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

**js**

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  shouldShow: function (index) {
    return (index + 1) % 2 === 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect that's it. I just have to change the number after % in js template helper in order to show the value only each X entries of my collection.

Comment: Yeah, you can also use a second parameter - like `{{#if shouldShow @index 3}}` could do it every 3rd one. That way you could have a single helper and use it in multiple places.