# Within {{#each}} clause, how do I find my element's sequential number?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to to do something like this:

```
  {{#each authors}}
    <li> {{row_number}}.  {{name}} </li>
  {{/each}}
```

Where `row_number` starts with 0.

Conventional approaches don't seem to work because of the reactivity (different rows updated at different times).

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815713/in-meteor-is-there-a-way-to-access-array-index-in-spacebars)?

Comment: This will return an author, not the author's number in the list.

Comment: No it won't. It will return the row number if use map as in the posted link

Comment: I get it now. Yup, it should work. Thank you. Although some have complained of performance implications. Do you think there would be any?

Comment: No, not on the client unless you are listing tens thousands of authors at once... but then this helper won't be your main issue. I'm marking this as a duplicate.