# How to get number of iteration on Meteor {{#each}}?

Tags: javascript, meteor, each

How can I get the index number of the {{#each}} list in Meteor? It seems like it should be really simple, but I can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816603 outlines the currently used solution. (Standard handlebars has `@index`, but it seems not to be supported in Spacebars yet: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2587 )

Answer (score 4):

Currently no build-in support for that. If you iterating cursor, use this:

```
return Collection.find().map(function (doc, index, cursor) {
  return _.extend(doc, {index: index + 1});
})
```

and use

```
{{#each .}}
  {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I changed 'Collection' to the name of my collection, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Works like a charm!