# Meteor 1.2 : A way to access {{../@index}}

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I use meteor 1.2

Here is my code :

```
{{#each steps}}
{{#each buttons}}
<button class="car-action-button" data-step-index="{{../@index}}" data-button-index="{{@index}}" data="{{../idOnMap}}" data-cid="{{../../cid}}">
</button>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

{{../@index}} should return the steps rank but doesn't return anything. Is ther a way to do that ?

Comment: You don't need coffeescript sugar (@), do you have index in object over which you are iterating? Because Meteor doesn't provide that value

Comment: It's a new functionnality of meteor : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815713/in-meteor-is-there-a-way-to-access-array-index-in-spacebars

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here is my solution :

```
{{#each steps}}
{{#let index = @index}}
{{#each buttons}}
<button class="car-action-button" data-step-index="{{index}}" data-button-index="{{@index}}" data="{{../idOnMap}}" data-cid="{{../../cid}}">
</button>
{{/each}}
{{/let}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope it help someone :)