# What is the correct way of getting the index of an array when iterating over it using Ember Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, indexing, handlebars.js

```
{#each controller.content.assetAllocation.class}}
    {{@index}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm trying to run the code above, which is supposed to output the index of the array, but it produces an error saying:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , "

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution is not as nice as I'd hoped, but this works:

```
{#each controller.content.assetAllocation.class}}
    {{_view.contentIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It is important to note that the value will not change if you add a new object to the array

Answer (score 4):

Here's my way:

```
{#each controller.content.assetAllocation.class as |item index|}}
    {{index}} - {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

The index is Zero-based numbering. So if you want to change it, just add an helper like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("indexBase1", function (value, options) {
        return value + 1;
});
```

And using it:

```
{#each controller.content.assetAllocation.class as |item index|}}
    {{indexBase1 index}} - {{item}}
{{/each}}
```