# Index in Each Helper in Emblem

Tags: emblem.js

I see that you can get the index within an each helper in handlebars with

```
{{#each array}}
    {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

which I found in [How to get index in Handlebars each helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper)

This doesn't seem to work in Emblem though:

```
ul
  each App.things
    li {{@index}}
```

`Uncaught Error: Emblem syntax error, line 1: Expected BeginStatement or DEDENT but "=" found.
=@index`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found the issue you opened on the emblem.js repository searching the web, the alternative syntax for #each did the trick:

```
ul
  each App.things
    li {{_view.contentIndex}}
```

Here is the link for people having the same issue using broccoli (and/or ember-cli) and emblem for more details: https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/issues/161#issuecomment-48853594

Hope this helps ;)