# handlebars problems with helper registration:

Tags: handlebars.js, helper

I created

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifItIsBelow3',function(value){
  if (value < 3)
  {
    return true;
  }else
  {
    return false;
  }
});
```

and wanted to use is on the page

in

```
{{#ifItIsBelow3 {{@index}}}}
              <div>{{artists.0.name}}: {{name}}</div>
              <div idName="{{artists.0.name}}: {{name}}" id="{{id}}1" style="background-image:url({{album.images.0.url}})" data-track-id="{{id}}" class="cover"></div>
          {{/ifItIsBelow3}}
```

but my handlebar helper is not working;
I have message

Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 3:
...      {{#ifItIsZero {{@index}}}}

in browser.

I loaded my handlebarHelper.js as a script on the page.
I am not sure if it was really loaded.
Should I place it in some very specific place?

all hints are welcome

Marcin

Comment: {{#index}} should be without {{ }}; We found it finally;

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as follow:

Javascript:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifItIsBelow3',function(value){
  if (value < 3){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#ifItIsBelow3 {{@index}}}}
     <div>{{artists.0.name}}: {{name}}</div>
     <div idName="{{artists.0.name}}: {{name}}" id="{{id}}1" style="background-image:url({{album.images.0.url}})" data-track-id="{{id}}" class="cover"></div>
 {{/ifItIsBelow3}}
```

Or for Index follow below answer:

[How to get index in Handlebars each helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper/30122739#30122739)

Thanks: