# how to give seperate id to a list of buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have been posting this same issue for last 2-3 days , nobody gave a proper solution.

Problem:

I have set of increment and decrement button in my shopping cart page to manage products quantity before checkout. I want all my decrease button to be disabled if the quantity is equals to 1. I have used set of IF statements to do that. But, those IF conditions are only working when my cart page contains one item at a time. I have founded the issue but getting no solution for that. The problem is that, the button id is same on each cases so it override one another. So, I want to give different different id's when each cart item is displayed on the page with  - and + buttons. How to make my code like that ?

Here's my code for both buttons and IF statements.

```
 {{#each products}}
            <tr>

                <td><img src="/product-images/{{this.product._id}}.jpg" 
style="width:70px;height:70px" alt=""></td>
                <td>{{this.product.Name}}</td>
                <td>Rs.{{this.product.Price}}</td>


                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info mr-3 cart-item-count " id="button(-)"
                        
onclick="changeQuantity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user._id}}',-1)">-</button>
                    <span id="{{this.product._id}}">{{this.quantity}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-info ml-3 cart-item-count" id="button(+)"
                        
onclick="changeQuantity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user._id}}',1)">+</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <div class="float-right pr-5 pt-5">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Total Rs. <span id="total">{{total}}</span></h3>
        <a href="/place-order" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" style="width:100%">Place Order</a>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
{{#each products}}
<h1 id="Quantity">{{this.quantity}}</h1>
{{/each}}
<script>
let Quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('Quantity').innerHTML);

//console.log(Quantity)

if (Quantity == 1) {
    document.getElementById("button(-)").disabled = true
} else {
    document.getElementById("button(-)").disabled = false
}

if (Quantity == 10) {
    document.getElementById("button(+)").disabled = true
} else {
    document.getElementById("button(+)").disabled = false
}

function changeQuantity(cartId, proId, userId, count) {
    count = parseInt(count)
    let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML)
    let qty = quantity + count
    //console.log(qty)
    if (qty > 1) {
        document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = false
    } else if (qty == 1 || qty == 10) {
        document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = true
    }

    if (qty == 10) {
        document.getElementById('button(+)').disabled = true
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button(+)').disabled = false
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/change-product-quantity',
        data: {
            cart: cartId,
            product: proId,
            user: userId,
            count: count,
            quantity: qty
        },
        method: 'post',
        success: (response) => {

            document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = quantity + count
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = response.total

            location.reload()

        }
})
}
```

Note: value of quantity in the above code is taken from Mongodb using Handlebars.

[image: Current Output]

As you can see this image that, the disabling effect only applied to first row of button not the rest.
This has to be solved .

Expected output:

All the - button must be disabled while page loads.

Thank You:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{{@index}}` inside your `id` attributes

h/t [How to get index in Handlebars each helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884960/how-to-get-index-in-handlebars-each-helper)

Comment: I'm getting the index. But,How can I iterate through it in javascript?. I need to get all the indexes in the javascript .so I can iterate through it.

Comment: You asked how to get unique `id`s -- I believe all you have to do is update your `id` attribute from `id="button(-)"` to `id="button(-){{@index}}"`

Comment: It's not working... please give a clear picture. If give like this how can i pass these index to javascript?