# Mustache.js iterate over all arrays

Tags: json, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm still busy trying to setup a JSON file to a HTML website. So if the json changes the changes are dynamically loaded in the HTML. Till this far i'm able to retreive the content and even request some content. But not everything that i want because the markup from the JSON is a bit weird.

Because of the cross-site protection I was not able to do a JSOP request directly, so i solved that with a little trick i saw somewhere. I've created a test.php that simply does:

That way I circumvent the cross-site protection, and everything works well. Only problem is that I can't iterate over all the arrays that i want. Currently i'm using the following script to do a JSOP call and get the data. And the output is a nice description between the `<li></li>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="episodes">
    </ul>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ps3scenefiles.com/json/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script id="episodes-template" type="text/template">

            <li>{{description}}</li>

    </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('http://ps3scenefiles.com/json/test.php', function(data) {
                var template = $('#episodes-template').html();
                var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                $('#episodes').html(info);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when you open the link to the JSON (http://ps3scenefiles.com/json/test.php), you see that the Episodes array has another array with just numbers. How can i create a list like

```
Episode: 1 
     Id:13605 Active:true Lang:en Link: url
     Id:16525 Active:true Lang:ru Link: url
Episode: 2 
     Id:14854 Active:true Lang:en Link: url
     Id:19445 Active:true Lang:ru Link: url
```

So to be clear, how can i do a mustache (or handlebars) templating to make it look like the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Handlebars helper as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962186/326543)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzAxf/1/) without styling, that prints out the data you expect (sort of, not all fields).

Here is the helper function -

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachkeys', function(context, options) {
  var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
  var ret = "";

  var empty = true;
  for (key in context) { empty = false; break; }

  if (!empty) {
    for (key in context) {
        ret = ret + fn({ 'key': key, 'value': context[key]});
    }
  } else {
    ret = inverse(this);
  }
  return ret;
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer. can you tell me what i have to change in this helper if i want to iterate over: http://trendico.ru/api/moviebox/get_tv_data?id=1&season=1 ? I still need the same data, but it seems that the episodes are nested.

Comment: The episodes seem to be of the same format, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzAxf/2/). I just replaced the episodes with the data from your new link.

Comment: Thank you. That means if i use that whole JSON as input, i can use this template? I tried replacing the JSON as in this http://jsfiddle.net/SzAxf/3/ fiddle. But no luck so far :(

Comment: Oh, the template expects only `episodes`. So in your case when `episodes` is nested, you need to pass `data.episodes`. Have updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SzAxf/4/