# how to display json keys and change it through handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Followed these articles:

[How to get index in handlebars each helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11884960/6836963)

[Mustache.js - display key instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8961939/6836963)

I am trying to display keys of json and then i want to change the name of key under that object.

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "msg":"The request to access the credit report successfully processed",
   "errors":{  

   },
   "arf":{  
        "TradeLine":{  
         "TradeLine":{  
            "Mortgage Accounts":[  
               {  
                  "SubscriberDisplayName":"abc",
                  "MonthsHistory":99,
                  "PaymentProfile":{  
                     "2017":{  
                        "1":"C",
                        "2":"C",
                        "3":"C",
                        "4":"C",
                        "5":"C",
                        "6":"C",
                        "7":"C",
                        "8":" ",
                        "9":" ",
                        "10":" ",
                        "11":" ",
                        "12":" "
                     },
                     "2016":{  
                        "1":"C",
                        "2":"C",
                        "3":"C",
                        "4":"C",
                        "5":"C",
                        "6":"C",
                        "7":"C",
                        "8":"C",
                        "9":"C",
                        "10":"C",
                        "11":"C",
                        "12":"C"
                     }
                 }],
```

i have created the table and in that i have displayed the other data. 
now in different row as heading i want to display 2017 and all the key values inside the 2017. But i want to change the key "1" as "jan" , "2" as feb and so on. 
I am getting table format but i am not getting the Key such as 2017,2016 etc.

My Code: 
Try 1 :

```
<thead class="thead-default">
                  <tr>
                    <th>{{SubscriberDisplayName}}</th>
                  </tr>
</thead>
    {{# repData}}
          {{#each arf.TradeLine.TradeLine.[Mortgage Accounts]}}
               <table id="RealEstateTbl" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                    {{#each PaymentProfile}}
                      <tr>
                        <th>Payment History (Upto 25 months)</th>
                        <th>{{this.key}}</th>
                      {{/each}}
                      </tr>
               </table>
          {{/each}}
    {{/ repData}}
```

Try 2:

```
Javascript/Handlers:
            var reportTemplate = $("#report-template").html();
            var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(reportTemplate);
            var reportData = theTemplate(this.ReportbyIDdata);
            $('body').html(theTemplate({repData: this.ReportbyIDdata}));
           // console.log(repData);
            Handlebars.registerHelper('eachkeys', function(context, options) {
                var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
                var ret = "";

                var empty = true;
                for (key in context) { empty = false; break; }

                if (!empty) {
                    for (key in context) {
                        ret = ret + fn({ 'key': key, 'value': context[key]});
                    }
                } else {
                    ret = inverse(this);
                }
                return ret;
            });

        }) 

{{# repData}}
          {{#each arf.TradeLine.TradeLine.[Mortgage Accounts]}}
               <table id="RealEstateTbl" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                    {{#eachkeys PaymentProfile}}
                      <tr>
                        <th>Payment History (Upto 25 months)</th>
                        <th>{{this.key}}</th>
                      {{/eachkeys}}
                      </tr>
               </table>
          {{/each}}
    {{/ repData}}
```

What to do to

1. display the year i.e key
2. change the keys inside the object ? i.e display "Jan" instead of "1" ?? -> PS: i haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

solved the first problem by

```
{{#each PaymentProfile}}
                  <tr>
                    <th>Payment History (Upto 25 months)</th>
                    <th>{{@key}}</th>
                  </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

but it is displaying as follows:

Payment History (Upto 25 months)    2015

Payment History (Upto 25 months)    2016

Payment History (Upto 25 months)    2017

I want 2017 first then 2016 and so on. 
how can i do that ?? 
Also please give some insights on my 2nd question too.